# export the Clips results to an txt file

Tags: clips

Im using Clips to build a Recommendation system with some business rules.
With the final results shown on the the Clips, I wish to export the results to an txt file.
Can anyone suggest me how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

you can use "save" or "bsave" commands  (take a look to basic guide).
Or you can redirect your console output to a file. It depends on how you run your CLIPS script.

Comment: Can I just write a piece of code to automatically direct the console output to a file ?  I mean as long as the user runs the script, the result will be saved as a txt file.

Comment: Use dribble-on/dribble-off commands to capture all output written to the console in a file.